# How to achieve the photo effect of "Live Christmas Music at the Americana in Glendale, California" by Chris Yarzab?

Tags: reverse-engineering, image-manipulation, effect

I came across the below photo while browsing Wikimedia Commons. ([Photo by Fourbyfourblazer](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Americanachristmasband.jpg))

My Question, how was this photo processed to obtain this effect?

HDR, Photoshop Filters, What?

[image: Photo by Fourbyfourblazer]

Comment: The photographer's name is Chris Yarzab. Maybe he'd be willing to share what he did if you ask him? http://www.flickr.com/photos/chrisyarzab/3053772197/

Comment: The effect here looks quite a bit different than the original that Kim linked. Did the wikipedia commons one have additional post processing done?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I used Photoshop with Topaz Labs Denoise and Adjust.

Comment: Well that's a pretty definitive answer then! :)

Comment: Lol, can't argue with that.

Comment: You should have seen my reaction when it was "you" replying. My mouth dropped open and I laughed out loud. What can I say? Hiding my adoration for your work with that photo is not possible. Simply wonderful! I can't wait to see more of your works on flickr. May your holidays be harmonious and offer you surprises like you just gave me. This was great!

Comment: Thanks for the appreciation. The photo is an early version of my work. There are far more talented people than me. If I just had some training I'm sure the quality of my work would be of greater interest. Using Photoshop Elements 9 with Topaz Labs filters has brought life to my dull photos. :-)

Comment: Amazing how nine words can get you 120 rep.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like [LucisArt](http://www.lucisart.com/) to me.  Could be Topaz Adjust, or any HDR program.